# c - interrupt a function call which is executing in a thread

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, function, interrupt

I have a DLL which contains a thread function whose pseudocode looks like:

```
volatile BOOL stopped = FALSE;

void StopEverything()
{
    /* Enter critical section */
    stopped = TRUE;
    /* Leave critical section */
}

void workerThreadFunc()
{
    Initialize();

    /* Checkpoint 1 */
    if(stopped)
    {
        /* Do cleanup */
        return;
    }

    doLaboriousTask1();

    /* Checkpoint 2 */
    if(stopped)
    {
        /* Do cleanup */
        return;
    }

    doLaboriousTask2();

    Uninitialize();
}
```

And in the code which uses this DLL, the cleanup function looks like:

```
void cleanup()
{
    StopEverything();

    /* Wait for all threads to exit */
    /* Do other cleanup */
}
```

My question is twofold:

1. Is there a better way to stop my `workerThreadFunc()` from executing instead of doing checks like that at various checkpoints?
2. Suppose `workerThreadFunc()` is stuck inside `doLaboriousTask2()` when the main application calls `StopEverything()`. Is there a way to *interrupt* `doLaboriousTask2()` and have it exit immediately?

Thanks!

Comment: Depending on context, one option might be to split the laborious tasks off into a separate process, which can then be terminated at will.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, Wouldn't having separate processes increase the overhead significantly due to more expensive context-switches?

Comment: Typically, process context switches don't add significantly to overhead, particularly on systems with multiple CPU cores.  But you'd need to profile your particular scenario to be certain.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, Yes true. But I always thought thread-switching was faster than process-switching

Comment: yes, but neither should be significant unless the processes are waiting on one another frequently.  When the subprocess is working independently, it will typically get at least one entire time-slice before being switched out.  The time taken to switch between processes is a very small fraction of a time-slice.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a better way to stop my workerThreadFunc() from executing instead of doing checks like that at various checkpoints?

Probably not. There's no fully reliable way to pre-emptively halt a thread in unmanaged code. Anything that purports to do that leads to [`TerminateThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717.aspx). And the documentation lists all sorts of dire consequences for using that function. For example:

> - If the target thread owns a critical section, the critical section will not be released.
> - If the target thread is allocating memory from the heap, the heap lock will not be released.
> - If the target thread is executing certain kernel32 calls when it is terminated, the kernel32 state for the thread's process could be
>     inconsistent.
> - If the target thread is manipulating the global state of a shared DLL, the state of the DLL could be destroyed, affecting other users of
>     the DLL.

You ask:

> Is there a way to interrupt doLaboriousTask2() and have it exit immediately?

Well, you could call `TerminateThread` but, for all the reasons described in the documentation, you almost certainly should not do that.

Comment: Yeah I didn't want to use `TerminateThread` for the same reasons. I actually came across [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71529/Exception-Injection-Throwing-an-Exception-in-Other) which describes a method to do so in C++ but it looks kind of scary since it directly modifies registers (or maybe it's just me).

Comment: I don't think that's really any better than `TerminateThread`.

Comment: So there really is no way? Also, what do you think of my checkpoint strategy?

Comment: The strategy you use in the question is fine. It's the way it is done in native code.

Comment: But the number of function calls and the amount of cleanup code is increasing and this method is becoming slowly unmanageable. I thought there might be a much more concise way to deal with this in C. Oh well.

Comment: @David: would it be fair to say that a thread which makes no Win32 calls, and doesn't use the C library or any external libraries, is safe to terminate?  Or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: @HarryJohnston, What if the thread is allocating memory on the heap?

Comment: @Harry If the thread is doing work that is simple enough that may be so

Comment: @AnishRam: you'd need to allocate memory ahead of time, although in principle you could allocate a single large block and then implement your own suballocator.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, Oh that's an interesting idea! I will definitely try and use that. Seems to be a more efficient approach if I can accurately predict how much memory the program will need.