# TerminateThread() returns error when terminating the thread

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, createthread

I have a ThreadA created using the `CreateThread` function. Inside ThreadA, another thread, ThreadB is created using the `CreateThread` function.

Now, I want to terminate ThreadB from ThreadA but the `TerminateThread` function fails.

Is it because ThreadA may not have the right to terminate ThreadB?  I am really confused with this situation.

Comment: In general, *never* use `TerminateThread` because you can leave locks held and cause all sorts of problems.

Comment: @RogerRowland : thank you for the post. I know TerminateThread is not a safe function but what else can be the alternative if I want to destroy my thread and all its resources at some stage of my code?

Comment: What you can do is make your thread wait on an event object, which you can use to signal termination from another thread. You can set a wait timeout of zero so your thread can do work while waiting to be terminated. An example [is in this SO answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1702206/2065121)

Comment: Just let the thread end itself. However, it would be good to see some source, when dicsussing this issue.

Comment: If you have control over both thread functions, then you can implement something like what [this Stack Overflow thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544255/c-interrupt-a-function-call-which-is-executing-in-a-thread) discusses. There seems to be no alternative (in C). What @RogerRowland, suggested works in a similar way.

Comment: To address your original question, what error code is returned from `TerminateThread`?  Can you show us some code demonstrating the issue?

Comment: @RogerRowland : I tried your suggestion and that seems to have solved the issue :) Thanks alot. P.S: You can post your comment as an Answer as I would like to accept it :)

Comment: @RogerRowland : I tried your suggestion and that seems to have solved the issue :) Thanks alot. P.S: You can post your comment as an Answer as I would like to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, never use `TerminateThread` because you can leave locks held and cause all sorts of problems. [As MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

[image: MSDN]

What you can do instead is to make your thread wait on an event object, which you can use to signal termination from another thread.

If you need to perform a periodic check for a terminate signal within some normal thread processing, you can set a wait timeout of zero so your thread can do still work while waiting to be terminated.

An example is in [this SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702172/terminating-a-thread-gracefully-not-using-terminatethread/1702206#1702206).